# How can I reduce tensorflow.js model training time when working with large data?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I would like to use tensorflow.js to train the model on the web, but if the data is very large, what techniques can reduce the training time of the model?

When I manually changed the backend of tensorflow.js to cpu, wasm, and webgl, I was able to confirm that the training speed was decreasing. Am I right about the right thing?

I heard that out-of-core learning can handle a huge amount of data, but I would like to try out-of-core learning with tensorflow.js. What should I do?